# Start a fixed delayed schedular when a method start and stop when finishes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I have a Spring Boot web application.

I want to start a fixedDelayed scheduled job when a method starts. And stop scheduled job when `someMethod` method finished. I read the documentation but I couldn't understand how. I want to wirte someting to db every 30 second while `someMethod` is still working.

Here is the pseudo code. Anyone has an idea?

```
public void someMethod() {

    //Start scheduledLogger() to work every 30 seconds

    //...
    //Do something taking long time

    //Stop scheduledLogger() job
}

private void scheduledLogger() {
    //Log to database
}
```

Comment: possibly this can help you http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public void someMethod() 
   {
       //Start scheduledLogger() to work every 30 seconds
       TimerTask tasknew = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                scheduledLogger();

            }
        };
       Timer timer = new Timer();

       // scheduling the task
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew, new Date(), 3000);      

        //Do something taking long time
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Stop scheduledLogger() job
        // terminating the timer
        timer.cancel();
    }

    private void scheduledLogger() {
        //Log to database
        System.out.println("Log to database at "+new Date());
    }
```